# После закрытие вопроса к заголовку добавляется [требует правки]?

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) в привилегиях, в главе "Что происходит, когда вопрос закрывается" первое предложение:

> После закрытия вопроса новые ответы к нему не принимаются, а к заголовку добавляется статусная строка `[требует правки]`. Через 5 дней, если вопрос не будет открыт повторно, статус изменится на `[закрыто]`.

Это сейчас работает? Ни разу не видел. В enSO такого нет:

> Once a question has been closed, it will no longer accept new answers and the label `[closed]` will be appended to the title.

Comment: Некоторое время назад перестало работать, теперь сразу закрыто

Comment: А русскоязычная справка протухшая лет на семь

Comment: Интересно, а почему избавились от подхода с требуемой правкой? Вроде как логично. И новички поэтому плодят новые вопросы, а не правят старые.